# passing an anonymous function as argument

Tags: r

Why does the following work:

```
foo <- function(x) {x}
curve(foo)
# plots the identity function between 0 and 1
```

And this does not:

```
curve(function(x) {x})
```

> Error in curve(function(x) { : 
>     'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'

And yet

```
# the anonymous function can be called 
foo(1) #1
(function(x) x)(1) #1


all.equal(foo, function(x) {x})
# TRUE
```

I tried various combinations of "quote()" and "expression()" with no results.

Comment: from `?curve` : expr : The name of a function, or a call or an expression written as a function of x. So `curve({x})` works for instance. You just have to remove the `function(x)`. You can also remove the brackets.

Comment: Oh, I had read the help but it made me try `curve(x)` and `curve(quote(x))` which both failed...

Comment: given that `x` isn't a function itself you need the brackets but you can use `curve(sin(x))` or `curve({sin(x)})` (to clarify my comment about removing the brackets)

Comment: Thank you for offering a working solution. Still, my question was more about _why_ it did not work, when both arguments are apparently equal.

Comment: I'll write an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?curve` states that `expr` (the first argument) should be the name of a  function, a call or an expression written as a function of x which will evaluate to an object of the same length as x.

Thus, `curve({x})` will yield the expected result.

As to why `curve(function(x){x})` returns an error, reading the code of `curve` will help. At the end of the function definition, we have :

```
y <- eval(expr, envir = ll, enclos = parent.frame())
    if (length(y) != length(x)) 
        stop("'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'")
```

and we have :

```
eval(function(x){x})
# function(x){x}
```

and `x` is defined in the function code as `seq.int(0, 1, length.out = 101)`.

So with the call we have the error as the `eval` as a length of 1 which is not what we wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the help page for `curve` does *not* say that 'expr' argument can be a function-object. The three types of accepted argument are "*name* of a function, or a call or an expression written as a function of x which will evaluate to an object of the same length as x." (Emphasis added.)

All of the following succeed:

```
curve( (function(x) {x})(x) )
curve( local(x)  )
curve( eval(x)  )
```

When you saw that ...

```
all.equal(foo, function(x) {x})
# TRUE
```

... it was saying that the language object attached to the name `foo` was the same as `function(x) {x}`. (The `all.equal.language`-function deparses the object(s) or object-names and compares the character results.)